# NextJS Stream error when i use multer with next-connect

Tags: typescript, next.js, multer

I'm still new into the NextJS community.

I'm using `Stream` class in some parts of my backend but Next was giving errors. It said `Stream` is not available in the `edge` environment

To fix this, I installed the [stream-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-browserify) library, and added the following settings.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    if(!config.resolve) {
      config.resolve = {}
    }

    if(!config.resolve.fallback) {
      config.resolve.fallback = {}
    }

    config.resolve.fallback.stream = require.resolve('stream-browserify')
    return config
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This fixed the constant error with `Stream`, but now errors like:

```bash
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (127kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
- error Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
    at <unknown> (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:46)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:46:27)
    at (middleware)/./node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (file:///home/natan/Área de Trabalho/anipapers/web/.next/server/src/middleware.js:315:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///home/natan/Área de Trabalho/anipapers/web/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js:37:33)
    at fn (file:///home/natan/Área de Trabalho/anipapers/web/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js:280:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js:5:20)
    at (middleware)/./node_modules/concat-stream/node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (file:///home/natan/Área de Trabalho/anipapers/web/.next/server/src/middleware.js:359:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///home/natan/Área de Trabalho/anipapers/web/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js:37:33)
    at fn (file:///home/natan/Área de Trabalho/anipapers/web/.next/server/edge-runtime-webpack.js:280:21)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:3:17)
    at (middleware)/./node_modules/concat-stream/index.js (file:///home/natan/Área de Trabalho/anipapers/web/.next/server/src/middleware.js:260:1) {
  digest: undefined
}
```

I need it just to use `multer` with `next-connect`

Comment: You probably are streaming a high payload, so data is truncating and cannot be parsed, so buffer library provided by node can help you.

Comment: @AloisoJunior The native library is not supported by NextJS

[A list of all supports](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/edge)

The error doesn't just happen when I call the endpoint, but every time the development server is started